# Why include headerfiles in c++ and not the entire library

Tags: c++, file, header, libraries

Well I have always wondered why won't anyone include the whole library instead of just a header file. Is it to reduce redundancy . Or some memory optimisation concept. I enjoy knowing these small fundamentals in programming.please someone explain it to me.thank you.

Comment: You need to include headers for the *declarations* and link against libraries (`.lib` or `.dll`) for the *implementation* (unless you use a header-only library). Otherwise you'll have a ton of unresolved externals because none of your classes and functions have definitions.

Comment: Amoung other reasons: the source code of your library (if you have it) may be huge, and you don't want to compile the whole library each time you compile your program.

Comment: More information [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html).

Answer (score 3):

> why won't anyone include the whole library instead of just a header
>   file. Is it to reduce redundancy

Including the whole library (i.e. both headers and sources) will be more redundant. As it works now, you have the library itself (*.lib*, *.dll*, *.so*, whatever), which has the compiled code. You also have the headers which only contain the definitions. When you are writing your own code, you need the definitions to know what is there in the library that you can use. When you compile your application, the already-compiled code from the library file is used. So, you do *not* have to compile the library yourself each time you want to use it.

If, instead, you were to use the complete library sources, you would have to compile them yourself from scratch. Apart from being inconvenient, this may also be:

- extremely time-consuming: what if it takes 5 hours to build the library?
- simply hard to do: what if the library has 100 dependencies, and you need to build/configure a lot of other stuff just to be able to compile it?

Comment: Yup, add to that the fact that some people don't want others to see their code and implementations of the libraries. So, they just provide you with headers to use the functions but without being able to see how the functions are implemented. (You know closed source people)

Answer (score 0):

Library Include bunch of files out of which only few are needed in our program. For e.g. When we are writing a normal c program we don't need to load Math.h header file  as this header file is included for mathematic operations. Inclusion of these files increases the overall compile time of the program.So its better to include only those header files whose functions are needed in program instead of including the whole library.